# Questions migrated to Meta do not have required tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, migration

To ask a question on Meta you have to choose one of the required tags (discussion, feature-request, bug, support, etc.) but when a question gets migrated over from another site, these tags are almost always absent.

Is this something that anyone should be concerned about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't see how we can have a better system than to just edit the required tag on there. I guess we could totally blow out the close dialog:

- Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com as a Discussion
- Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com as a Bug
- Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com as a Support
- Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com as a Feature Request
- Belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com as an **Impressive Example of Stupidity**

But, really, I think we just have to be diligent and edit the tags as they come through. Otherwise, there's no way to systematically tell what should go where.

Comment: I was thinking about this myself. I am not a fan about trying to get the people closing the question to give it the appropriate tag. I've said in the past that I believe that your 3,000 rep gives you the ability to say "no this doesn't belong here" but it doesn't give you the ability to make decisions to really say how something should operate on another site. This conundrum is also why I posted my other question right after this as a way to possibly solve this problem.

Comment: Well, hell, I'm browsing in between reboots at the moment, so I missed that one.

Comment: I don't think this is such a good idea. It's better to handle this sort of thing on the target site.

Comment: @Kyle: I was being facetious with the close menu...

Comment: @Eric, I was guilty as well of not reading your answer closely enough to realize you were not suggesting adding it as part of the close reason.

Comment: The last close reason in your list would only be available on Fridays, right?

Comment: @balpha: Sadly, stupidity doesn't take days off.