# Notify site moderators of migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, flags, migrated-questions

After originally posting this question ([Questions migrated to meta do not have required tags)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/questions-migrated-to-meta-do-not-have-required-tags) it got me thinking about a feature request that could be very useful.

When questions get migrated, I think it would be good practice to send up a moderator only flag when a question is migrated to a new site. I think it is often the case that sometimes questions get moved from one site to another and there need to be some type of changes made (such as tagging) to make the question more in line with the site's conventional standards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that perhaps having a tab in the 10k+ rep tools that listed recently migrated questions (perhaps only ones without a required tag) would be better. I think we should limit the mod flag to issues where time is an issue - otherwise it would be difficult to separate what needs to be done immediately (closing, locking, deleting) and questions that simply need to be retagged.

In the meantime, a simple [tag search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/-discussion+-feature-request+-bug+-support+-faq) will reveal all the questions without the required tags. (No way I know of to filter to only migrated)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how much flagging is there on a daily basis on Meta?

Comment: I do really like the idea of having a list of recently migrated questions. I think overall that could work better than a flag, but I do like the immediacy of the flag as well. When I originally the only active mod on SuperUser the most flags I ever saw at one time were 8 and that was only for three topics that just got flagged by multiple users. I am not sure how heavy the flagging is on the other sites (I would imagine SO gets hammered).

Comment: @Eric: There are only a handful every day (mostly under 5) which is why they're so rapidly acted upon (if the moderators deem it necessary).

Comment: The flag frequency on SO varies wildly.  Some days it's pretty quiet, but I've logged in and seen the queue in the high teens before.  I don't see it get that high normally, but that could be because Marc is a few time zones ahead of me.